# SE site about fun

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a StackExchange site for fun things to do in life in general and in detail? Is there a common name for that kind of study?

I'd like to know what activities might be fun for me, how to find out what else I might be interested in based on what I know I like. And then I'd like to further dig into the roots of fun and learn how I can make other, less appealing activities, more entertaining. But I don't know what I don't know, so it would help a lot if I could just read top questions from such a site and see what things other people are asking about and what answers are out there.

Not sure this would be a Q&A site with definitive objectively correct answers (if it doesn't exist yet), but possibly most accepted by the users.

Comment: Currently not. You could give it a try on Area51 and propose a new site.

Comment: @juergend I tried to figure out how Area51 works, and I think it's too hard for me. I'm not that good in making good arguments in my propositions. I bet other users might do better, if they like this idea.

Comment: Log into Area51 and then: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=life

Comment: What would a typical question be for such a site? Perhaps that would narrow down "fun" a bit more. I have a feeling you might be thinking about "Leisure Management", but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Bart a typical or a good one, considering current SE standards for technical and most other sites? I guess a typical question would be "I like this and that, what else is there I could enjoy?"

Comment: I'm guessing that would be too recommendation-y for SE.

Comment: Well, that is kind of the point. Surely it could be rephrased to "What kind of activities would a person who likes this and that also enjoy?" but still not allowing a single correct answer. I guess it all depends on the person's previous experiences and details about his life, that helps determine the correct list of things for them. And that's psychology, I think. Then it boils down to determining the most common past experiences for an average person, but that would become too specific. (*it should be noted that I'm bad at asking questions*)

Comment: Consider that not all types of questions or topics are suitable for SE sites.

Comment: @Oded now I'm guessing this might never be a Q&A site, and therefore probably not a SE one. Still, I was interested in finding out what SE users think about this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This question was not about memes and humor specifically, so closing it as a duplicate of a similar but newer (by 4 years!) question is wrong. I suppose they are related, but not exact duplicates. If anything, the newer question is a subset of this one, not the other way around.

Comment: @user1306322 the newer one got official seal of a final "no", so I felt it is more proper to close this way, to make it clear there is no such site and will most likely never be.

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to know what activities might be fun for me, how to find out what else I might be interested in based on what I know I like.

These are recommendation questions, which are banned on *most* sites on the SE network, with very few exceptions, because they work out so poorly in our Q&A format.

> And then I'd like to further dig into the roots of fun and learn how I can make other, less appealing activities, more entertaining.

We have a [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site, there's a [Psychology](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60281/psychology) proposal on Area 51 which you could follow, and this *may possibly* fall within our [Cognitive Science](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) beta site's topic (but I'm not sure about that). Unfortunately, [Gamification](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44478/) was an unsuccessful beta site.

Other than that though, you might not find much unless you have *specific problems* needing answering. The internet is *full* of research on fun and the psychology around it, on game design, and a *ton* of things surrounding the entire topic. Go searching for them, and for the game development news sites like [Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/).

Comment: I guess I'll follow Psychology for now. Maybe in a few years things will become different and a non-Q&A site about recommendations for entertainment will be open.

Comment: And right now I consider game development the shortest path to figuring out how to fun.

Comment: @user1306322 That entire area pretty much revolves around the question of how to fun, so that's a good start. ;)